# "un-sudo" cordova platform w/o removing and adding it

Tags: cordova, command-line, sudo

I Did a mistake and created the android platform using `sudo su`

As a result, I can't build/run Android with out using sudo and I can't run/build IOS using sudo. So it's a bit tricky ( I have to remember not to build IOS also using sudo )

I know I could remove the platform as sudo and add it again as my-user, but I customized several things in the android platform dir and don't want to lose them...

Any ideas?

Comment: already tried `chmod` or `chown`?

Comment: No, I Didn't. I'm not really familiar with handle files using command-line ( or terminal, in my case, for mac )

Comment: try `chmod +777 -R .` in your project folder (you need to google, I am on Windows, so I am  guessing here).

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet, DO NOT DO +777. This will make your files insecure. It makes all files executable and writeable by anyone.

Comment: @JesseMonroy650 So what do you suggest? ( I Didn't do it )

Comment: Sorry, I've been putting this off because I've had a headache. Unfortunately, you must do what you don't want. I will explain in the answer. It will take about 15 to 20 minutes. Busy right now.

Answer (score 0):

@ToniMichelCaubet,
at this point you should be using NPM and other tools to help you install the Cordova tool set. As you have realized, you do NOT need to use `sudo` with the tool set. However, a few packages incorrectly require the use of `sudo`.

NPM is a fairly good at package management. When it downloads a package it has a file named `package.json` that tells it where all the files are and how to treat them. In theory, you can look at these files and determine what you need to do. In addition - if you are using a *nix type system, you can use [`locate(8)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/locate) to find more files. You will find there is a cache in your user directory name `~/.npm`. However, if you have used `sudo` there is a chance many of the files are stored in `/root`. You can check the later with `sudo ls -al /root`.

**CAUTION:** *There is chance you might set the permissions of a file incorrectly, as such you would render you packages un-usable.*

On Linux and *BSD and all UNIX-style systems, the CLI tools you will need include:

- [chown](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chown)(1) - change file ownership, this include owner and group
- [chmod](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod)(1) - change file mode (ownership) bits

Your commands should look like this for *most* files.

- `chown --recursive yourLoginName:yourLoginName *`

Change ownership of files recursively in the current directory to "you". In *nix systems you also have a group that belongs to you.

- `chmod --recursive 644 *`

Change permision of files recursively in the current directory so that you  (6) can read and write, and your group (4) and the "public" (4) can read the file.

**example:** `ls -l` has a permission of `664` and the owner and group is `jessem`

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jessem jessem  5701 Dec 24 01:38 scratchpad.here
```

You will need to use `sudo` with these utilities to change anything set by `sudo`. Yes you need to `sudo` to un-`sudo` the files that have incorrect permissions for general use. Let me know, if you decide to do this. **I recommend you uninstall and reinstall.**

Comment: Wow, What an elaborated answer!! I'll give it some thoughts and let you know ;) ( looks like I'm going to remove and add the platform.. )

Comment: After making a backup of the project dir, I tried `$ chown --recursive toniweb:toniweb *` but is returning `chown: illegal option -- -
usage: chown [-fhv] [-R [-H | -L | -P]] owner[:group] file ...
       chown [-fhv] [-R [-H | -L | -P]] :group file ...` any idea? Also tried `chown -R toniweb:toniweb *
chown: toniweb: illegal group name`

Comment: Good thing you made a backup. This is the type of issue I anticipated. You should be using `sudo /path/to/chown`. You are on your own now.

Comment: NOTE: not all UNIX systems are the same. You can use `man chown` to see how yours works.